# Creating multiple forms with a single model

Tags: django, modelform

I want to create multiple forms using single model. Is it possible?

First I made a model including all the fields I need.
**models.py**

```
class AcademicsUpto10(models.Model):
    PRE_PRIMARY_SUBJECT_CHOICES = (
        ('Abacus', 'Abacus'), 
        ('Handwriting Basic', 'Handwriting Basic'),
        ('English Phonetics', 'English Phonetics'),
        ('English', 'English'),
        ('KG Academic Class', 'KG Academic Class'),
    )
    SUBJECT_1TO5_CHOICES = (
        ('All subjects', 'All subjects'), 
        ('Vedic Maths', 'Vedic Maths'),
        ('Mathematics', 'Mathematics'), 
        ('Science', 'Science'), 
        ('English', 'English'),
        ('Hindi', 'Hindi'), 
        ('Environmental Studies', 'Environmental Studies'),
        ('Mathematics - Science (Combo)', 'Mathematics - Science (Combo)'),
        ('Handwriting English/Hindi', 'Handwriting English/Hindi'),
    )
    SUBJECT_6TO10_CHOICES = (
        ('Mathematics', 'Mathematics'),
        ('Science', 'Science'),
        ('Computer Science', 'Computer Science'),
        ('English', 'English'),
        ('Social Science', 'Social Science'),
        ('Sanskrit', 'Sanskrit'), 
        ('Environmental Studies', 'Environmental Studies'),
        ('French', 'French'),
        ('German', 'German'),
        ('Spanish', 'Spanish'),
        ('Mathematics - Science (Combo)', 'Mathematics - Science (Combo)'),
        ('Olympiad Maths/Science', 'Olympiad Maths/Science'),
    )
    BOARD_CHOICES = (
        ('CBSE', 'CBSE'),
        ('ICSE', 'ICSE'),
        ('State Board', 'State Board'),
        ('International Board', 'International Board'),
    )
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
        ('Flexible to get the best tutor', 'Flexible to get the best tutor'),
    )
    DAY_CHOICES = (
        ('Monday', 'Monday'),
        ('Tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
        ('Wednesday', 'Wednesday'),
        ('Thursday', 'Thursday'),
        ('Friday', 'Friday'),
        ('Saturday', 'Saturday'),
        ('Flexible on days to get the best tutor', 'Flexible on days to get the best tutor'),
    )
    SLOT_CHOICES = (
        ('Early Morning (6AM-8AM)', 'Early Morning (6AM-8AM)'),
        ('Morning (8AM-12AM)', 'Morning (8AM-12AM)'),
        ('Early Afternoon (12PM-3PM)', 'Early Afternoon (12PM-3PM)'),
        ('Late Afternoon (3PM-5PM)', 'Late Afternoon (3PM-5PM)'),
        ('Early Evening (5PM-7PM)', 'Early Evening (5PM-7PM)'),
        ('Late Evening (7PM-10PM)', 'Late Evening (7PM-10PM)'),
    )
    unique_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ticket_size = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=1000, blank=True)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    standard = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    pre_primary_subject = MultiSelectField(choices=PRE_PRIMARY_SUBJECT_CHOICES, default='Abacus', blank=False)
    subject_1to5 = MultiSelectField(choices=SUBJECT_1TO5_CHOICES, default='All subjects', blank=False)
    subject_6to10 = MultiSelectField(choices=SUBJECT_6TO10_CHOICES, default='Mathematics', blank=False)
    subject_final = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank = True)
    board = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=BOARD_CHOICES, default='CBSE', blank=True)
    day = MultiSelectField(choices=DAY_CHOICES, default='Flexible on days to get the best tutor', blank=False)
    slot = MultiSelectField(choices=SLOT_CHOICES, default='Early Morning (6AM-8AM)', blank=False)
    gender_preference = models.CharField(max_length=35, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='Flexible to get the best tutor', blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    plot = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    contact = models.IntegerField(validators=[
                                    MaxValueValidator(9999999999),
                                    MinValueValidator(7000000000)],
                                  blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.name)
```

Then I wrote some **forms.py**

```
class AcademicsPrePrimaryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AcademicsUpto10
        fields = [
            'pre_primary_subject', 'day', 'slot', 'gender_preference',
            'plot', 'street', 'landmark', 'name', 'contact', 'email'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'pre_primary_subject': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'for-check-box'}),
            'day': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'for-check-box'}),
            'slot': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'for-checkbox'}),
            'gender_preference': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'plot': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Plot Number', 'class':'for-field-before'}),
            'street': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Street', 'class': 'for-field-before'}),
            'landmark': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Landmark', 'class': 'for-field-before'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name', 'class': 'for-field-before'}),
            'contact': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number', 'placeholder': 'Mobile Number', 'class':'for-field-before'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email ID', 'class': 'for-field-before'})
        }


class Academics1to5Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AcademicsUpto10
        fields = [
            'subject_1to5', 'board', 'day', 'slot', 'gender_preference',
            'plot', 'street', 'landmark', 'name', 'contact', 'email'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'subject_1to5': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'for-check-box'}),
            'board': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'day': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'for-check-box'}),
            'slot': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'for-checkbox'}),
            'gender_preference': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'plot': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Plot Number', 'class':'for-field-before'}),
            'street': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Street', 'class': 'for-field-before'}),
            'landmark': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Landmark', 'class': 'for-field-before'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name', 'class': 'for-field-before'}),
            'contact': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number', 'placeholder': 'Mobile Number', 'class':'for-field-before'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email ID', 'class': 'for-field-before'})
        }


class Academics6to10Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AcademicsUpto10
        fields = [
            'subject_6to10', 'board', 'day', 'slot', 'gender_preference', 
            'plot', 'street', 'landmark', 'name', 'contact', 'email'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'subject_6to10': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'for-check-box'}),
            'board': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'day': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'for-check-box'}),
            'slot': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'for-checkbox'}),
            'gender_preference': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'plot': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Plot Number', 'class':'for-field-before'}),
            'street': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Street', 'class': 'for-field-before'}),
            'landmark': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Landmark', 'class': 'for-field-before'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name', 'class': 'for-field-before'}),
            'contact': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number', 'placeholder': 'Mobile Number', 'class':'for-field-before'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email ID', 'class': 'for-field-before'})
        }
```

From here I want to save the subjects in three forms at same place (this subject is to displayed in admin panel), I am not able to figure this out.

Sample view - **views.py**

```
def standard8(request):
    form = Academics6to10Form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        form.save(commit=False).address = request.POST['location']
        form.save(commit=False).standard = 'Standard 8'
        form.save(commit=False).field = 'Academics'
        form.save()
        message = "A new query has been added in " + str(form.standard)
        message += "Name: " + str(form.name)
        message += "Mobile Number: " + str(form.contact)
        send_mail(emailSubject, message, emailFrom, emailList, fail_silently=False)
        return render(request, 'thanks.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'allForms/acadsstandard8.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Do you want to have multiple forms in admin? Not clear what you want to achieve from your last statement

Comment: I created three forms using three subject fields, after that I want to save the results from any of those to "subject_final" field. I want only one instance in admin which displays this "subject_final" field. This field is to be serialized later as well.

Comment: I understand you have three types of Subject Fields in your model (`subject_1to5`, `subject_6to10` and `subject_final`), but I don't understand when you say you have one form for each field. Maybe if you explain what you want to achieve, we could better understand

Comment: Basically I don't want to make 3 models which have different subject choices only and rest of the fields are the same. So I made one model with three subject choices ( pre_primary_subject,subject_1to5, subject_6to10). Corresponding to these three subject fields, 3 forms are created. After one of the form is filled i want to save the options from these subject field to "subject_final" field. This subject_final field is to be displayed in admin panel.